# Extracting Data from JSON Using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's a test jason feed

```
{"MEMBERS":[{"NAME":"Joe Bob","PET":["DOG"]}, {"NAME":"Jack Wu","PET":["CAT","DOG","FISH"]}, {"NAME":"Nancy Frank","PET":["FISH"]}]}
```

What I'm attempting to do is extract data if PET contains CAT or FISH or both. Another user suggested a filter as such:

```
$filter = array('CAT', 'FISH');
// curl gets the json data (this part works fine but is not shown for brevity)
$JSONarray=json_decode($JSONdata,true);
foreach($JSONarray['MEMBERS'] as $p) {
       if (in_array($p['PET'], $filter)) {
       echo $p['NAME'] . '</br>';
        }
}
```

But it's not returning anything.

Note: edited based on comments below

Comment: `$JSONarray[MEMBERS]` needs quotes around `MEMBERS`. Same issue with `PET` and `NAME` (which is spelled wrong).

Comment: Sorry, typo above NAMR is NAME

Comment: any errors? that code looks full of them...

Comment: Always use error_reporting(E_ALL); when you're coding, you would have seen the notices in your code "Use of undefined constant MEMBERS" and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
foreach($JSONarray['MEMBERS'] as $p) {

    if (array_diff($p['PET'], $filter) != $p['PET']) {
        echo $p['NAME'].'</br>';
    }
}
```

- Remember to always **use quotes** when you are trying to access an element of an associative array. Without quotes, PHP tries to interpret it as a constant (throwing a Notice on failure). So instead of `$a[index]` do `$a['index']`. Please also see [Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)
- In your code, `$p['PET']` will be an array of pet names, not one pet name. Testing with `in_array()` won't be successful, because it will try to find the whole array in `$filter`. In my code example, I used [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which will find the difference between the two arrays, then I compare it to the original array. If they match, the `$filter` pets were not found.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Use strings to access the array** and not uninitialized constants.
2. **`$p['PET']` is an array**. You have to use some other method to compare it against `$filter`, e.g. [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

   ```
   foreach($JSONarray['MEMBERS'] as $p) {
       $diff = array_intersect($filter, $p['PET']);
       if (!empty($diff)) {
           echo $p['NAME'].'</br>';
       }
   }
   ```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/xgM3ttkD)

Comment: This gave "Can't use function return value in write context"

Comment: Yes, that works now. What's more robust? array_intersect or array_diff

Comment: @John: Both is robust. But I would say that testing an array whether it is empty is faster than comparing it to another array. Still, @bazmegakapa gave the far better explanation for your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use quotes on your array keys:

```
$JSONarray['MEMBERS']
$p['PET']
$p['NAME']
```

Secondly, you can't use in_array as it assumes 'needle' to be **the** array('CAT', 'FISH') and not any one of it's values. 
(The parameter order was also the other way around)

Here's a method using [array_intersect](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
foreach($JSONarray['MEMBERS'] as $p) {
    $test = array_intersect($filter, $p['PET']);
    if (count($test)>0) {
        print( $p['NAME'].'</br>' );
    }
}
```